# strlen was not declared in this scope - C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I need to install a simulator in my ubuntu. It is written in C++ and when I try to run make, I get this error `strlen was not declared in this scope`. Any solution to overcome this error?

Comment: Anyone know why this error would *not* occur on certain systems e.g. gcc 4.5.3 32-bit Linux?

Comment: @gcbenison: `gcc` is a C compiler which does not need "c" libraries to be included (ie. `cstring`,`cstdlib`,whatever). However `g++` which is a C++ compiler does need them included.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should do it :

```
#include <cstring>
```

Comment: I also get lrand48 was not declared in this scope error. Can you help me?

Comment: @Vivek: according to [google](http://www.google.com/#&q=lrand48+include), `#include <cstdlib>` could help

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <cstring>
```

Your program may also be looking for `::strlen` instead of `std::strlen`.  If this is the case, try

```
using std::strlen;
```

Answer (score 1):

did you install all packages you needed?

1. try g++ --version and see if it gives something.
2. check /usr/lib/include/ for string.h.

If those things are not there, you need to check if the correct package is installed or not.

Comment: Now really, what would complain about `strlen()` being inaccessible without a compiler?

Comment: The magical elves that live inside the computer would. They are also responsible for most errors that seem to appear and then disappear without intervention.